# ideas on how to prepopulate(preset) dynamic form based on user selection?

Tags: node.js, html, forms, dynamicform

I'm hoping to get some ideas/guidance on how I can go about implementing something on a web app I'm developing.

Scenario: User encounters a HTML5 form with option to dynamically add/delete rows of inputs in a table

```
[table]
        [1st row] [input 1] [input 2] [X - delete]
        [2nd row] [input 1] [input 2] [X - delete]
        ...
        [add new row]
```

I'd like to add a `select box` where the dropdown selection pre-populates the dynamic form with rows/input values based on the selection.

I'm mostly familiar with client side scripting and a little PHP, but I've recently started to learn node.js. I have a mysql database, but I'm not sure the best way to move forward.

I'm not asking for you to code this for me! Just want to know how you would conceptualize this type of user feature so I can make this a learning project.

thanks as always!

Answer (score 0):

One way: give the `<select>` boxes an `onchange="functionNameHere(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"` attribute, then do something like:

```
<select onchange="functionNameHere(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
...
<script>
const functionNameHere = (value) => {
  if(value=="Some Option Value"){ 
    document.getElementById("target-field-id").value = "newValue"
 } else if(value=="Other Option Value"){ ...} 
}
</script>
```

or something along those lines, depending on the value or field you are trying to manipulate. You may be looking to `setAttribute` or even `innerHTML` your target div(s), field(s), or input(s).

Also, if you want to dynamically populate fields based on multiple selections, it would be wise to have different onchange function names for each select field

Comment: Oh, and the above uses ES6 JS, depending on your environment you may just want a classic function, such as `var functionNameHere = function(value){if...}`